# google analytics reporting Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

hello i'm working on dashboard of a web app made with React, this dashboard supposed to report some information from google analytics and render them, i just want to know how i can get these informations from Google analytics with the React because i've been looking for that in a lot of ressources ,but i founded just how to track views of screen, how to track events, but i steel don't know the way to get informations from google analytics and render them.

[image]

You can see in the image the information that i want to report.
because the information in the image are in french i m going to tell You what it render in fact this is an image of google analytic api and it's telling me that a user visited the Contact and GoogleAn pages about 4 times, now me i want to report this information (number of visit) to my dashboard and don't know how

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the Google Analytics API to achieve this.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js